# How to get the Row Mouseover to all cells in a row

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have created a cell template for a row. IsMouseOver Trigger is working perfectly on a single cell, but it doesn't trigger IsMouseOver property on other cells in the same row.

This is the cell template I have created

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="GridViewNewCellCoreTemplate" TargetType="telerik:GridViewCell">
                <Grid>
                    <Border x:Name="PART_CellBorder"
                            Background="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding VerticalGridLinesBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{Binding VerticalGridLinesWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource GridLineWidthToThicknessConverter}, ConverterParameter=Right}"/>
                    <Border x:Name="SelectBorder"
                            Background="{StaticResource BrushHighlight}"
                            Opacity="0.2"
                            Visibility="Collapsed"
                            BorderThickness="{Binding VerticalGridLinesWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource GridLineWidthToThicknessConverter}, ConverterParameter=Right}"/>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ContentPresenter"
                                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Grid>
                <!--Grid View row selection style only trigger-->
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsInEditMode" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_CellBorder" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BrushBackground}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <!--chk for mouse hover--> 
                    <!--<MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="helpers:GridViewHelper.IsReadOnlyMouseOver" Value="true"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>-->
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Property="helpers:GridViewHelper.IsReadOnlyMouseOver" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Property="DisplayVisualCues" Value="False"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="SelectBorder" Property="Opacity" Value="0.1"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="SelectBorder" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                     <!--selection is working-->
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Property="DisplayVisualCues" Value="False"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="SelectBorder" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsCurrent" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_CellBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource BrushHighlight}"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_CellBorder" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="{StaticResource DisabledOpacity}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>

            <Style x:Key="GridViewCellReadOnlyStyle" TargetType="telerik:GridViewCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource GridViewCellCoreStyle}">
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource GridViewNewCellCoreTemplate}"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#fff6f6f6"/> 
                <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            </Style>
```

How can I get the IsMouseOver for all cells in the same Row, if one cell gets Mouse over?

Comment: So it works for the first cell it enters but not for the others? Or do you want this to be triggered when full row is selected? Sorry, I am struggling to understand what you mean.

Comment: Correct, whenever I enter into a single cell it works but does not work for other cells. @XAMlMAX

Comment: So when your mouse enters first cell it works, when you then move to another cell it doesn't? Sorry but you didn't specify which question was correct one.

Comment: Your question no 1 is correct.( i.e So it works for the first cell it enters but not for the others?) .It works perfectly for all individual cells,but I want them all to get triggered whenever anyone of them is triggered ? @XAMlMAX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hightlight all cells of the row you should use a Multi**Data**Trigger and bind to the `IsMouseOver` property of the parent `GridViewRow`:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=telerik:GridViewRow}}" Value="True"/>
        <Condition Property="helpers:GridViewHelper.IsReadOnlyMouseOver" Value="true"/>
        <Condition Property="DisplayVisualCues" Value="False"/>
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter TargetName="SelectBorder" Property="Opacity" Value="0.1"/>
    <Setter TargetName="SelectBorder" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

Comment: I have tried it and its showing error.( InvalidOperationException: Must have non-null value for 'Binding'.)

Comment: Did you really replace the MultiTrigger with a Multi*Data*Trigger as per my answer? Then it should work. It certainly does for me :)

Comment: It work's only when you remove all property attribute from MultiDataTrigger Condition. ie If i remove these codes `<Condition Property="helpers:GridViewHelper.IsReadOnlyMouseOver" Value="true"/>
        <Condition Property="DisplayVisualCues" Value="False"/>` then it works perfectly.